# Procedural collection operations into java stream or reactive stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reactive-programming

How to transform this "old style" procedural java code into at least java 8 streams or reactive streams using Flux and Mono. 
My goal is to achieve good foundations for using that code in concurrent non-blocking web environment.

I want to have a constant number of `Elem` elements in whole system and at the same time smaller or bigger number of `places` available for those elements.

Visually it might looks something like that for 8 elements, 12 places and 3 objects (containing each of them their own list of `Elem`s):

s1 `[Elem(1), Elem(2), Elem(3), Elem(4)]` 
s2 `[Elem(5), Elem(6), Elem(7), Elem(8)]` 
s3 `[FREE, FREE, FREE, FREE]`

call for s1 `requestElem()` 
call for s1 `requestElem()` 
call for s2 `requestElem()`

s1 `[Elem(1), Elem(2), FREE, FREE]` 
s2 `[Elem(5), Elem(6), Elem(7), FREE]` 
s3 `[FREE, FREE, FREE, FREE]`

...and currently those three elements are waiting to be returned in random order...

call for s3 `returnElem(4)` 
call for s3 `returnElem(8)` 
call for s3 `returnElem(2)`

s1 `[Elem(1), Elem(2), FREE, FREE]` 
s2 `[Elem(5), Elem(6), Elem(7), FREE]` 
s3 `[Elem(4), Elem(8), Elem(3), FREE]`

Of course order of those operations might be different and randomly choosen.

```
class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private final int size = 4;     // size of s1, s2, s3
    private BlockingDeque<Elem> places;
    private int numOfElem;
    private BlockingDeque<Elem> additionalElems;

    public void requestElem() {
        if (numOfElem > size) {
            numOfElem--;
            additionalElems.pop();
            return;
        }
        if(!places.isEmpty()){
            places.pop();
            numOfElem = places.size();
        } else {
            System.out.println("empty: " + name + ", waiting for new elements...");
        }
    }

    public void returnElem(int id) {
        if (numOfElem >= size) {
            numOfElem++;
            additionalElems.push(new Elem(id));
            return;
        }
        if(places.size() < size){
            places.push(new Elem(id));
            numOfBicycles = places.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Is this possible? Can you provide me some useful tips or resources?

Comment: I personally would not use streams for this.

Comment: So this kind of code/problem is "generally" not suitable for using reactive programming ideas etc?

Comment: It is not quite clear what the problem (in a sense of "task") is, so I judge only from your code which is very imperative. There may be a declarative/functional way to solve the problem as well, but it's hard to reason without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like a stack structure. pushing elements into stack will occupy places. polling elements will free them. You can use stack structure for this.

Comment: From the code posted here, Streams API is not appropriate for a solution. To use Streams, you would have to iterate through the whole collection on each edit, making it less efficient than the current "pointer" based implementation. Depending on the root requirements, however, Streams could be used - but then we're choosing the framework before we've decided on the problem that needs a solution (which IMHO is a bad idea).

Comment: This looks like a fixed size queue - just use a `BlockingQueue`. If you want to make something a bit more reactive, you could use a ring buffer - have a `Flux` of incoming items (`requestElem`) and a `Flux` of outgoing items (`returnElem`). Without knowing what you want to achieve, it's impossible to say what the right answer is. The current code is obviosuly not threadsafe, so I don't really understand what the purpose of it is...

Comment: I've edited my original post, I hope it will help understand my problem better.